# Plot edges conditional on speed limit in python's OSMnx

Tags: python, osmnx

I need to plot edges conditional on the `speed_kph` values such that edges with `speed_kph` > A are color X and edges with `speed_kph` < A are color Y. Is this possible in OSMnx?

From:
`map = ox.graph_from_place('Paradise, California', network_type='drive')`

I can plot:  `ox.plot_graph(map,bgcolor='#FFFFFF',edge_color='#000000',node_color='#000000');`

Impute speed and travel time as described in other docs:  `map_cons_speed = ox.add_edge_speeds(map) map_cons_speed = ox.add_edge_travel_times(map_cons_speed)`

Then extract edges: `gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(map_cons_speed)`

But I can not figure out how the plot edges conditional on their speed limit.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of edge colors based on that attribute:

```py
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('Paradise, California', network_type='drive')
G = ox.add_edge_speeds(G)
ec = ['y' if d < 50 else 'r' for u, v, d in G.edges(data='speed_kph')]
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, node_alpha=0.1, edge_color=ec)
```

Or use the `plot.get_edge_colors_by_attr` function to assign colors from a color map based on attribute values:

```py
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('Paradise, California', network_type='drive')
G = ox.add_edge_speeds(G)
ec = ox.plot.get_edge_colors_by_attr(G, 'speed_kph', cmap='plasma')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, node_alpha=0.1, edge_color=ec)
```